# Remove dependency of a library from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easing

The previous developer has included the jquery like this -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this jquery there is a line as

```
this.pos=f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]](this.state,c,0,1,i.duration)
```

So there is another js added which is in my project as - `jquery.easing.1.3.js`

It seems this js is causing a bounce effect on hover, but I am not sure. SO I have commented out the code which is including the easing.js. Now the browser console is throwing the error -

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function
    at fx.step (jquery.min.js:4)
    at h (jquery.min.js:4)
    at fx.custom (jquery.min.js:4)
    at fx.show (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDivElement.g (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.dequeue (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jquery.min.js:2
```

So my basic requirement is to show/hide a div on click instead on the hover which is being done by easing.js. So I want to remove easing.js dependency. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a more current version of jQuery?

Comment: As I said this was added be someone else, not me.